# How to give task board access to the clients in TFS2015?

Tags: tfs-2015

Could anyone can help to give access for the board or task board access to the external users/clients?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add the uses into the team project that you want they access, then grant them necessary permission.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252477.aspx